# Getting data from json by key, not index, with flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I have a json table with this structure;
 `{id: 1, deviceid: 1, devicenumber: 11, number1: 1, number2: 2, number3: 3, number4: 0, number5: 5, date: 0000-00-00 00:00:00}`

**With this code, I can pull data from the json table according to the index. but what I want is to pull all the json data and search in all keys.**

because i will not always know the index number but deviceid key number is always available. That's why it's to match the captured data with the data I have and get other correct information.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I will assume you are going to work with [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) so my answer is based around that but you should get the basics out of it

I would create a class for your json data first

```
Class ClassName {
final String? testText

ClassName({this.testText});

factory ClassName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return ClassName(testText: json['test_text']);
 }
}
```

Then fetch the url and parse it on your main widget, that fetch should look something like this:

```
Future<ClassName>? futureData;

Future<ClassName> fetchData() async {
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
    url));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
  // then parse the JSON.
  return ClassName.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
} else {
  // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
  // then throw an exception.
  throw Exception('Error');
}
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureData = fetchData();
    super.initState();
    }}
```

Later on when using FutureBuilder you can use this data as a future

```
FutureBuilder<ClassName>(
  future: futureData,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData) {
      return Container(
        child: Text(snapshot.data!.testText),)}},
```

Comment: `builder: (context, snapshot) {` constantly getting an error in the square brackets here.

type'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String,dynamic>' i am getting error message

Comment: @user I would suggest looking at this [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing) that should clear out your issues